# How to use marked-highlight from a VSCode extension?

Tags: typescript, npm, vscode-extensions, highlight.js, javascript-marked

If I use the example code [from here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/marked-highlight) in a standalone TypeScript file, then it works fine.

```
import { Marked } from "marked";
import { markedHighlight } from "marked-highlight";
import hljs from 'highlight.js';

const marked = new Marked(
  markedHighlight({
    langPrefix: 'hljs language-',
    highlight(code, lang, info) {
      const language = hljs.getLanguage(lang) ? lang : 'plaintext';
      return hljs.highlight(code, { language }).value;
    }
  })
);


marked.parse(`
\`\`\`javascript
const highlight = "code";
\`\`\`
`);
```

If I add the same code into `extension.ts` of a VSCode extension, then I get this error:

```
Argument of type 'import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked", { with: { "resolution-mode": "import" } }).MarkedExtension' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked").MarkedExtension'.
  Types of property 'extensions' are incompatible.
    Type 'import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked", { with: { "resolution-mode": "import" } }).TokenizerAndRendererExtension[] | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked").TokenizerAndRendererExtension[] | null | undefined'.
      Type 'import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked", { with: { "resolution-mode": "import" } }).TokenizerAndRendererExtension[]' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked").TokenizerAndRendererExtension[]'.
        Type 'import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked", { with: { "resolution-mode": "import" } }).TokenizerAndRendererExtension' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked").TokenizerAndRendererExtension'.
          Type 'TokenizerExtension' is not assignable to type 'TokenizerAndRendererExtension'.
            Type 'TokenizerExtension' is not assignable to type 'TokenizerExtension & RendererExtension'.
              Type 'import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked", { with: { "resolution-mode": "import" } }).TokenizerExtension' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked").TokenizerExtension'.
                Types of property 'start' are incompatible.
                  Type 'import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked", { with: { "resolution-mode": "import" } }).TokenizerStartFunction | undefined' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked").TokenizerStartFunction | undefined'.
                    Type 'import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked", { with: { "resolution-mode": "import" } }).TokenizerStartFunction' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked").TokenizerStartFunction'.
                      The 'this' types of each signature are incompatible.
                        Type 'import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked").TokenizerThis' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked", { with: { "resolution-mode": "import" } }).TokenizerThis'.
                          The types of 'lexer.options.extensions' are incompatible between these types.
                            Type '{ renderers: { [name: string]: import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked").RendererExtensionFunction; }; childTokens: { [name: string]: string[]; }; inline?: import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked").TokenizerExtensionFunction[] | undefined; block?: import("/home/...' is not assignable to type '{ renderers: { [name: string]: import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked", { with: { "resolution-mode": "import" } }).RendererExtensionFunction; }; childTokens: { [name: string]: string[]; }; inline?: import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked", { with: { "resolution-mode...'.
                              Type '{ renderers: { [name: string]: import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked").RendererExtensionFunction; }; childTokens: { [name: string]: string[]; }; inline?: import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked").TokenizerExtensionFunction[] | undefined; block?: import("/home/...' is not assignable to type '{ renderers: { [name: string]: import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked", { with: { "resolution-mode": "import" } }).RendererExtensionFunction; }; childTokens: { [name: string]: string[]; }; inline?: import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked", { with: { "resolution-mode...'.
                                Types of property 'renderers' are incompatible.
                                  Type '{ [name: string]: import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked").RendererExtensionFunction; }' is not assignable to type '{ [name: string]: import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked", { with: { "resolution-mode": "import" } }).RendererExtensionFunction; }'.
                                    'string' index signatures are incompatible.
                                      Type 'import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked").RendererExtensionFunction' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked", { with: { "resolution-mode": "import" } }).RendererExtensionFunction'.
                                        The 'this' types of each signature are incompatible.
                                          Type 'import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked", { with: { "resolution-mode": "import" } }).RendererThis' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked").RendererThis'.
                                            The types of 'parser.options.tokenizer' are incompatible between these types.
                                              Type 'import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked", { with: { "resolution-mode": "import" } }).Tokenizer | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked").Tokenizer | null | undefined'.
                                                Type 'import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked", { with: { "resolution-mode": "import" } }).Tokenizer' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked").Tokenizer'.
                                                  Types of property 'lexer' are incompatible.
                                                    Type 'import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked", { with: { "resolution-mode": "import" } }).Lexer' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/foobar/node_modules/marked/lib/marked").Lexer'.
                                                      Types have separate declarations of a private property 'tokenizer'.ts(2345)
```

The error is coming from the argument of `new Marked(...)`

What's happening here, and how can I fix it?